# Change sequence of dynamic sku for bundle product in cart

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, bundled-product, sku, bundle-product

How can I change the order of the associated option's SKUs when they are added to the bundle product SKU in the cart page?

So, for example, a bundle product (SKU "Bundle1") is added to the cart with two associated products (SKUs "Simple1" and "Simple2"). The option Simple1 is listed before Simple2 on the bundle page, but in the cart, the dynamic SKU is "Bundle1-Simple2-Simple1". How can I make it "Bundle1-Simple1-Simple2" -- to match the order in which the simple products are displayed on the bundle page?

I'm using Magento CE 1.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though you probably set the position for the bundle options, when generating the dynamic SKU the order is given by the position you set for each individual bundle option product.

So you should also set the position for 'Simple1' to 1 and for 'Simple2' to 2.

I rounded in red the position based on which the SKUs are ordered for the dynamic SKU.

[image]